# Passing integer arguments to variadic template where accepts floatings

Tags: c++17, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to code the "generalized beta function" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Multivariate_beta_function) in C++.

Here is my work:

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto sum(Args&&... args) {
    return (args + ...);
}

// Beta(a1, a2, ..., an) = Beta(a1, a2 + ... + an) * Beta(a2, ..., an)
template <std::floating_point F, typename... Ts>
constexpr F multivariate_beta(F a1, Ts... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) > 0);
    F value = std::beta(a1, sum(args...));
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 1)
        return value;
    else
        return value * multivariate_beta(args...);
}
```

This function works nicely for the following test cases:

```
std::cout << multivariate_beta(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) << '\n';  // should output 1 / 3!
std::cout << multivariate_beta(2.0, 3.0, 4.0) << '\n'; // should output 2! * 3! / 8!
```

But fails with the following test cases:

```
std::cout << multivariate_beta(1, 1, 1, 1) << '\n'; // compile error
std::cout << multivariate_beta(2, 3, 4) << '\n'; // compile error
```

The compiler complains that the function only accepts `std::floating_point` concept typed arguments,
so (1, 1, 1, 1) and (2, 3, 4) aren't valid arguments.
I'm not happy with this, because 1, 1, 1, 1 and 2, 3, 4 are implicitly convertible to floating-point type.

How can I enforce implicit conversion to floating point in these cases?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(Self-answer)
A workaround:

```
template <typename A>
concept Arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<A>;

template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto sum(Args&&... args) {
    return (args + ...);
}

// Beta(a1, a2, ..., an) = Beta(a1, a2 + ... + an) * Beta(a2, ..., an)
template <std::floating_point F = double, Arithmetic A, typename... Ts>
constexpr F multivariate_beta(A a1, Ts... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) > 0);
    F value = std::beta(a1, sum(args...));
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 1)
        return value;
    else
        return value * multivariate_beta(args...);
}
```

The bad thing is that the return value type is not parametrized, just forced to `double`. Looking for a better solution...

(edit): Solved this! Yes!

Comment: `F` is always `double`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, but I think calling ```multivariate_beta<float>(1, 1, 1, 1)``` makes F as ```float```. Calling ```multivariate_beta(1, 1, 1, 1)``` makes F as the default type, ```double```.

Comment: Because I want to leave an option to control the return type. Making that as ```auto``` will always force the return type as ```double```, as I know, because the return type of ```std::beta``` is ```double```.